# remove spaces and all symbols from target column

Tags: sql-server

I need to remove ALL spaces and ALL symbols, except letters and numbers from target table (for example dbo.Products), target column(fro example products_fullTextSearch) in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a User defined `scalar function`

Then use that function update the table

**Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION Udf_remove_symbol_space(@chr VARCHAR(max))
returns VARCHAR(max)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @cntr   INT=1,
              @temp   VARCHAR(5),
              @result VARCHAR(max)=''
      WHILE @cntr <= Len(@chr)
        BEGIN
            SET @temp = Substring(@chr, @cntr, 1)

            IF @temp LIKE '[a-z]'
                OR @temp LIKE '[0-9]'
              BEGIN
                  SET @result += @temp
              END
            SET @cntr+=1
        END
      RETURN @result
  END
```

**Demo**

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (chr VARCHAR(max))

INSERT #test
VALUES('1234567890abcdefghijk~lmonpqrstuvwxyzA BCDEFGHIJKLMONPQRSTUVWXYZ.-#,/\&%();:+@_*?|=')

UPDATE #test
SET    chr = dbo.Chrtst1(chr) 

select * from #test --1234567890abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMONPQRSTUVWXYZ
```